# EF safe lambda combination - (x,y) => x > y into (x) => x > constant

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have a SQL table wherein marked records are periodically "swept up" and deleted. I need to replicate this dataset, once for performance and twice to temporarily persist the deleted records.

I started by writing a wrapper around `DbSet<T>` to do some conditional caching of the dataset.

The cache is initialized at startup, then periodically updated.

I have an initialization predicate, for example:

```
Func<Type_x, bool> predicate = entity => true
```

Which is used to initialize:

```
cache(dbset.Where(predicate));
```

Then later I will update based on a second predicate, which has two parts:

```
// a function to get value of Type_y from dbset (dbset is DbSet<Type_x>)
Type_y preUpdate = dbset => dbset.Select(row => row.LastModified).Max()

// the problem predicate
Func<Type_x, Type_y, bool> = (dbset, preUpdate) => dbset.LastModified > preUpdate;
```

How do I get from the latter `Func<Type_x, Type_y, bool>` to a EF safe predicate `Func<Type_x, bool>`?

For clarity, the second parameter `preUpdate` of type `Type_y` will be computed and then needs to be combined into "the problem predicate" so that it 1. becomes a predicate of type `Func<Type_x, bool>` and 2. results in a clause in the generated SQL something like `WHERE [TABLE].[LAST_MODIFIED] > SOME_VALUE`

I think I can use the `ExpressionVisitor` but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by LegionMammal978's answer, what I needed was something like this:

`Func<ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, T>, Expression<Func<T, bool>>> updatePredicateBuilder`

Which I used:

```
CachedSet<DbView>.Get(this, DbViewDbSet,
    (DbView entity) => true,
    (DbSet<DbView> set) =>
    {
        var k = set.Select(e => e.Value.LastModified).Max();
        return g => g.LastModified >= k;
    });
```

note: without the block `set => { /* here */ }`, EF would pull back all the records to the runtime before executing the clause.

For clarity, within the update method:

```
var pred = this.updatePredicateBuilder(this.cachedDbSet);
var result = baseDbSet.Where(pred).ToList() /* materialize */;
```

Answer (score 1):

An option...

```
Func<Type_y, Func<Type_x, bool>> pred = preUpdate => dbset => dbset.LastModified > preUpdate;
```

(I haven't tested, you may have to add more parentheses.) Then, to use it:

```
Func<Type_x, bool> created = pred(myPreUpdate);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I feel stupid I didn't think of it. Your answer is almost spot on!